# Display rows where any value in a particular column occurs more than once

Tags: python, pandas

I want to display all the rows where any value in the column - "Website" occurs more than once. For example -  if a certain website "xyz.com" occurs more than once, then I want to display all those rows. I am using the below code -

```
df[df.website.isin(df.groupby('website').website.count() > 1)]
```

Above code returns zero rows. But I can actually see that there are so many websites that occurs more than once by running the below code -

```
df.website.value_counts()
```

How should I modify my 1st line of code to display all such rows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with `subset='website'` and `keep=False`:

```
df[df.duplicated(subset='website', keep=False)]
```

Sample Input:

```
  col1  website
0    A  abc.com
1    B  abc.com
2    C  abc.com
3    D  abc.net
4    E  xyz.com
5    F  foo.bar
6    G  xyz.com
7    H  foo.baz
```

Sample Output:

```
  col1  website
0    A  abc.com
1    B  abc.com
2    C  abc.com
4    E  xyz.com
6    G  xyz.com
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. There is another confusion. After using the above line of code, I get 200 rows (which means 200 rows have duplicate websites). When I use df.drop_duplicates(subset='website'), it drops 2500 rows. Why is that happening? Should it not just drop 200 rows?

Comment: If you want to drop all duplicates, you'd use `df.drop_duplicates(subset='website', keep=False)`.  By default, `drop_duplicates` keeps the first instance of a duplicate and then drops the rest, unless you specify otherwise with `keep`.  That doesn't explain the behavior you're seeing though, and testing `drop_duplicates` works as expected for me.

Comment: You might want to dig a little deeper and see what rows were dropped that aren't in the `duplicated` output.  Investigating that could help explain the discrepancy.

Comment: `drop_duplicates` will drop all duplicate rows except first. So you see 200 rows from above code, means unique rows are 200 and all other are duplicates of these 200, so it drops 2500. Check how much rows are remaining after dropping the duplicates. I think you will again get 200